# Coming late response from server while abort the jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I am getting late ajax response from PHP server when we abort the ajax request.
I am using codeigniter framework for server script.

**Javascript Code:**

```
cblcurrentRequest = $.ajax({
            url: baseurl + 'Login/getChannelBrand/' + brand_id, 
            type: 'post', 
            async: true, 
            cache: true, 
            data: '',
            beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#tw').html("");
                    $('#fb').html("");
                    $('#inst').html("");
                    $('#yt').html("");
                if (cblcurrentRequest != null) {
                    cblcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
                if (firsttwcurrentRequest != null) {
                    firsttwcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
                if (firstfbcurrentRequest != null) {
                    firstfbcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
                if (firstigcurrentRequest != null) {
                    firstigcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
                if (firstytcurrentRequest != null) {
                    firstytcurrentRequest.abort();
                }

                if (twcurrentRequest != null) {
                    twcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
                if (fbcurrentRequest != null) {
                    fbcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
                if (igcurrentRequest != null) {
                    igcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
                if (ytcurrentRequest != null) {
                    ytcurrentRequest.abort();
                }

            },
            success: function (result) {

                var channelBrandList = JSON.parse(result);
                facebookBrandName = channelBrandList['FacebookChannel'];
                twitterBrandName = channelBrandList['TwitterChannel'];
                youtubeBrandName = channelBrandList['YoutubeChannel'];
                instagramBrandName = channelBrandList['InstagramChannel'];
                YelpBrandName = channelBrandList['YelpChannel'];

                console.log(facebookBrandName);
                console.log(twitterBrandName);
                console.log(youtubeBrandName);
                console.log(instagramBrandName);
                console.log(yelpBrandName);

            }
        })
```

**Login Controllor**

```
function getChannelBrand($brandID) {

        $channelBrandList = $this->Model_brand->getChannelBrandList($brandID);

        $channelbrand_array = array('BrandId' => $channelBrandList[0]->BrandId,
            'BrandName' => $channelBrandList[0]->BrandName,
            'FacebookChannel' => $channelBrandList[0]->FacebookChannel,
            'TwitterChannel' => $channelBrandList[0]->TwitterChannel,
            'YoutubeChannel' => $channelBrandList[0]->YoutubeChannel,
            'InstagramChannel' => $channelBrandList[0]->InstagramChannel,
            'YelpChannel' => $channelBrandList[0]->YelpChannel
        );

        echo(json_encode($channelbrand_array));

    }
```

**Model Code:**

```
 function getChannelBrandList($brandID) {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM brands where BrandId='.$brandID);
        if (count($query->result()) > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return $query = "";
        }
    }
```

**Json Response:**

```
{
 "BrandId":"26",
 "BrandName":"jeep",
 "FacebookChannel":"jeep",
 "TwitterChannel":"jeep",
 "YoutubeChannel":"thejeepchannel",
 "InstagramChannel":"jeep",
 "YelpChannel":null
}
```

**Console log:**

[image]

Please suggest,if any configuration needed on framework level or anything else.

Thanks,
Sameek

Comment: consider two things will faster your query 1. Use query like`select col1, col2` not `select *`, 2. Use array for returned result instead of object. array is faster than object.

Question: Can you show the time for the request?

Comment: Without ajax abort it takes -1076ms. with ajax abort it takes: 22925ms,also include screen shot which show the time frame.

Comment: what is your `pconnect` settings? in database.php

Comment: 'pconnect' => FALSE,

Comment: try `pconnect' => TRUE`

Comment: I have set pconnect' => TRUE but not effect seemed.

Answer (score 0):

This will speed  littel up if you use your query like below

Fatch only one `row` and use `num_rows()` to count number of rows and `return false`

**Model**

```
<?php
function getChannelBrandList($brandID) {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM brands where BrandId='.$brandID);
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->row();
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
function getChannelBrand($brandID) {
   $channelBrandList = $this->Model_brand->getChannelBrandList($brandID);
    if($channelBrandList){
            $channelbrand_array = array('BrandId' => $channelBrandList->BrandId,
                'BrandName' => $channelBrandList->BrandName,
                'FacebookChannel' => $channelBrandList->FacebookChannel,
                'TwitterChannel' => $channelBrandList->TwitterChannel,
                'YoutubeChannel' => $channelBrandList->YoutubeChannel,
                'InstagramChannel' => $channelBrandList->InstagramChannel,
                'YelpChannel' => $channelBrandList->YelpChannel
            );

            echo(json_encode($channelbrand_array));
    }
    else{
       echo "error";
    }

        }
```

Comment: it's slow only when ajax is abort, on other cases it work without any issue.